# Unable to display the list properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am trying to display a list in flutter. The list has 2 parts, one is the parent name and under that, I have the subcategories. I am fetching the data using an API and trying to create checkboxes using the fetched data. I am unable to understand how to display the lists properly. As posted in the image, the main header is being displayed equal to the number of categories it holds. I want to display a single header and the subcategories under it. Kindly Help.[image: As you can see here, the main header is being shown equal to the subcategories it contains. I want to display the main category once and the subcategories below under the main category as checkboxes.]

Function for List Builder

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].p_cat_name),
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].c_cat_name),
                      leading: Checkbox(
                        value: CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index] =
                            !CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index],
                        onChanged: (bool? val) {
                          setState(() {
                            CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index] =
                                !CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index];
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
```

Function for adding data to the list

```
  Future<List<CategoryFiltersList>> getCategoryList() async {
var url = Uri.parse(
   urlhere );
final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  'st_search': '',
};
final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

Response response = await post(
  url,
  headers: headers,
  body: body,
  encoding: encoding,
);

var schemeBody = response.body;
var jsonData = json.decode(schemeBody);

List<CategoryFiltersList> categoryFiltersLists = [];
for (var sch in jsonData) {
  // String credentials = sch['isin'];
  // Codec<String, String> stringToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
  // Body.encoded =
  //     stringToBase64.encode(credentials); // dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=

  CategoryFiltersList categoryFiltersList = CategoryFiltersList(
    sch['mf_cat_id'],
    sch['p_cat_name'],
    sch['c_cat_name'],
  );

  if (sch['mf_cat_id'] != null) {}

  categoryFiltersLists.add(categoryFiltersList);
  CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus.add(false);
}

return categoryFiltersLists;
```

}

Json Data:

```
flutter: [{mf_cat_id: 6, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Value_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 7, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Large_Cap}, {mf_cat_id: 8, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Large_&_Midcap}, {mf_cat_id: 9, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Multicap}, {mf_cat_id: 10, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Midcap}, {mf_cat_id: 11, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Small_Cap}, {mf_cat_id: 13, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Focussed_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 14, p_cat_name: EQUITY, c_cat_name: Dividend_Yield_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 15, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Arbitrage_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 16, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Conservative_Hybrid_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 17, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Equity_Savings_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 18, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Dynamic_Asset_Allocation_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 19, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Balanced_Advantage_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 20, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Aggressive_Hybrid_Fund}, {mf_cat_id: 21, p_cat_name: HYBRID, c_cat_name: Multi_Assest_Allocatio<…>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView.builder` builds this for every one of your responses:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].p_cat_name),
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].c_cat_name),
          leading: Checkbox(
            value: CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index] =
                !CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index],
            onChanged: (bool? val) {
              setState(() {
                CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index] =
                    !CategoriesDsiplay.userStatus[index];
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

The problem with this is that your app builds a new `ExpansionTile` for every element in your response list.
To fix this you have to find out which and how many 'p_cat_name's your response has and build an `ExpansionTile` for every `p_cat_name`. As a child it should have another `ListView.builder` that builds a ListTile for every element from response array that has the same `p_cat_name` as the parent (you can do this with if statement checks).

Comment: I do understand that, but the problem is how should I go about writing the code for it? Any suggestions?